# Error estimation of N for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I'm facing an awful time trying to understand the 3rd and the 4th line of reasoning. Not only does the bound of the summation changes but also the variables changes from f(n) to f(n+1).

Explaining in a very simple intuitive manner would be ideal.

I can easily see the direct inequality
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}f(n)\leq \int_{N}^{\infty}f(x).dx$$

but not the "steps" in between

Answer (score 0):

Set $n = r + 1$; then the first term of the sum $$\sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} f(n)$$ corresponds to $r + 1 = N + 1$, or $r = N$, and substituting gives that the summand $f(n)$ is $f(r + 1)$. Hence, in terms of $r$, the sum is
$$\sum_{r = N}^{\infty} f(r + 1).$$
Now, renaming $r$ to $n$ gives the equality in question.